# Run Python script when a file has been added to a folder

Tags: scripts

Hi I am looking for some python script which runs automatically when a file has been added to a folder. is it really possible?. if yes can some one send some scrpts please.thanks in advance

Comment: Python -> watchdog. Examples: https://pythonhosted.org/watchdog/quickstart.html I can understand the dupe but it is a different q and has a slighly different answer. TS is looking for a python method to watch for files. So that is different than "run python script when files has been added".

Answer (score 0):

Python has a module called ["watchdog"](https://pythonhosted.org/watchdog/quickstart.html) that does exactly what you want.

- Create a watchdog from the example. The example only echoes to console so you can add logic there to do what you want to do.
- Execute the watchdog from a systemd service you create.

I made tons of these and when you get the hang of them it takes less than 15 minutes to create one from scratch.

Comment: Doesn't that need the script to be running constantly/launched every few seconds? Why not use inotify instead?

Comment: I totally agree with @terdon. [inotifywait](https://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait) is awesome.

Comment: Me too but it is not what is asked in the question :-) and servers don't have an inotifywait by default